# Shopify update cart.item_count using AJAX

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, shopify

On the product detail page of my `Shopify` site when you click "`Add To Cart`" the page uses `AJAX` to do its thing. BUT there is a variable named `cart.item_count` that does not update unless the page refreshes.

**Question:** How to get AJAX to update the `cart.item_count` on that page.

**Below is the code for the HTML page:**

```
        <div id="mini-cart" >

            <span class="cart_count_info">Cart ({{ cart.item_count }})</span>//THIS SPAN IS WHAT NEEDS TO BE UPDATED 

        </div>

         <p id="add-to-cart-msg"></p> //THIS "P" IS UPDATED BY THE AJAX WITH MESSAGING SEE BELOW JAVASCRIPT

          <form action="/cart/add" method="post" class="variants" id="product-actions" enctype="multipart/form-data">
              //TOOK OUT SOME OF THE FORM DATA THAT IS NOT NEED FOR THIS EXAMPLE

          </form>
```

**JavaScript Code.** There is a line of code at the bottom that updates some copy on the same page... If I can update my `cart.item_count` variable that is already found on he page.

```
function addToCartSuccess (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/cart.js',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: updateCartDesc
  });
  $('#add-to-cart-msg').hide().addClass('success').html('Item added to cart! <a href="/cart" title="view cart">View cart and check out &raquo;</a>').fadeIn();

$('span#cart_count_info').load(Cart ({{ cart.item_count }})); 
//MAYBE HERE IS WHERE I CAN ADD MY CODE TO UPDATE THE VARIABLE I NEED. MY CODE IS JUST A GUESS SINCE ID DON'T DO MUCH JAVASCRIPT PROGRAMMING.


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove

```
$('span#cart_count_info').load(Cart ({{ cart.item_count }}));
```

and replace it for "UpdateCartDesc" function bellow (see your success message)

```
function updateCartDesc(data){
  var $cartLinkText = $('.cart_count_info').html(data.item_count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking it as its related to header when you click Add to Cart, you get the updated number of products in your Cart.

Just add class **`cart-count`** to the div. Your structure should look like this:

```
#pageheader > .cart-summary > .cart-count
```