# Shopify: displaying cart's item_count dynamically

Tags: jquery, shopify, rivets.js

We have the cart.item_count displayed in the header. That's fine for most pages. But on one page, we dynamically add items to the cart, and we want the changes to be reflected in the cart summary in the header.

I'm thinking we need RivetsJS for this to work; so we'd have a one-way binding. I tried a couple of ways:

```
<span rv-text="cart.item_count"></span>
```

And:

```
{ cart.item_count }
```

The first showed up empty, the second displayed the curly braces and cart.item_count, literally.

What am I doing wrong? Do I need to do a rivets.bind() somewhere?

Comment: the second is double curlies `{{ cart.item_count }}`

Comment: Double curlies get picked up by Liquid, and just get rendered when the page is served; they don't get the binding we're looking for here. That's what we had originally. Now we want the dynamic binding.

Comment: are you working in a liquid template?

Comment: @Ronnie It's in a snippet, in a template. Yes.

Comment: sounds like you need to make an ajax get request to this API https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api#get-cart

Comment: I'm willing to give that a go. But I think the rivets thing is what this is for. I'll work on the AJAX solution while I wait for a rivets solution. Thanks.

Comment: rivet would have to get the data from somewhere though. I use angular, which is also a data binder. I would have to either get the data initially and increment that value or just do a get on cart.js every time.

Comment: or this, which would be kind of hacky. If you cart already displays 0, get that via the DOM, set it as a variable and whenever the user clicks the 'add to cart' button that value is increased. I suggest my first solution

Answer (score 2):

As **@Ronnie** commented, you should use [Shopify's Ajax API](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api).

There's plenty of other questions & answers on Stack Overflow with examples of how to do this, here's just a few:

- [Shopify update cart.item_count using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17387667/1367622)
- [Shopify.onItemAdded update #cart and cart.item.count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26347107/1367622)
- [If cart item count is three – hide add to cart | shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27312118/1367622)

[For example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27312588/1367622):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://your-store.myshopify.com/cart.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) { 
        var item_count = data.item_count;

        // Update the item count in your header here...
    }
});
```

You could also use [Shopify's jQuery wrapper library](https://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/themes/can-i-use-ajax-api#wrapper-libraries). See [`Shopify.getCart()`](http://mayert-douglas4935.myshopify.com/pages/api):

```
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// GET cart.js returns the cart in JSON.
// ---------------------------------------------------------
Shopify.getCart = function(callback) {
  jQuery.getJSON('/cart.js', function (cart, textStatus) {
    if ((typeof callback) === 'function') {
      callback(cart);
    }
    else {
      Shopify.onCartUpdate(cart);
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Yes, I'm using the first option (w/ $.get() ), but it has to be done as the success option of the addItem; otherwise, the item_count is not guaranteed to be accurate. But for some reason it's not running the success option function.  :(  I wish I could share code in comments...

Comment: @NotoriousWebmaster is it the `$.get()` that's failing, or `addItem`?

Comment: addItem isn't failing: the item *is* added. But the success function doesn't seem to be run.

Comment: @NotoriousWebmaster Hmmm... I haven't used CartJS but if the success callback is not firing I would suggest [adding an error callback and logging any error you might be getting](http://cartjs.org/pages/guide#core-api-callbacks). If you still cant get it working, maybe switch to `Shopify.addItem()` instead and see if you can get that working... Or take a look at the CartJS event [`cart.requestComplete`](http://cartjs.org/pages/reference#events).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<strong data-cart-render="item_count"></strong>
```

and make sure your JS looks like this:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">

     jQuery(function() {
          CartJS.init({{ cart | json }}, {
              "dataAPI": **true**,
              "requestBodyClass": "loading",
              rivetsModels: {
                "customer": {{ customer | json }},
                "product": {{ product | json}},
                "cart" : {{ cart | json }}
              }
          });
     });

  </script>
```